# Determinate which method returns true in or operator

Tags: ruby, return, return-value

I have:

```
def user_validation
  first_user_valid? || second_user_valid?
end
```

and I don't only want to return true/false but also want to return which method returns the true (maybe both?). I do have:

```
def user_validation
  return true if first_user_valid?
  return true if second_user_valid?
end
```

so far. But this does not seem very intuitive to me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the return value you expect for each case (of the four)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an array of responses:

```
def user_validation
  [first_user_valid?, second_user_valid?]
end
```

This way you can know that the first returned `true`, and the other `false`...

```
# => [true, false]
```

Comment: Suppose `@x = 0: def first_user_valid?; @x == 0; end; def second_user_valid?; (10 % @x) == 2; end`?

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i change the return from boolean to int. Doing that, you can handle which statment returning specifics numbers for that.

Comment: I would avoid hard-coding integers for status. Creates difficult-to-maintain code.

Comment: Return an array with true/false isnt a good pratice too. If you specify a list with status code, it should be a good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the method itself separately for the different users?

```
def user_validation(user)
    return user_valid?
end

if(user_validation(user_1))
    //user_1 is valid
end

if(user_validation(user_2))
    //user_2 is valid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
result = %w|first_user_valid second_user_valid|.inject(nil) |memo, m|
  (memo ||= []) << m.tr('_', ' ') if public_send("#{m}?")
  memo
end

if result # at least one is valid
  puts result.join ', '
else      # none is valid
  puts 'None is valid :('
end
```

Result here might be either `nil` (`falsey`), or the string like:

```
"first user valid, second user valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_validation
  valid = ((which = :first) && first_user_valid?) || 
   ((which = :second) && second_user_valid?)
  which = :neither unless valid
  [valid, which]
end
```

To illustrate:

```
def first_user_valid?;  true; end
def second_user_valid?; true; end
user_validation #=> [true, :first]

def first_user_valid?;  false; end
user_validation #=> [true, :second]

def second_user_valid?; false; end
user_validation #=> [false, :neither]
```

In general, when using `||`, you don't want to evaluate the second expression if the first evaluates `true`, as in some cases that may raise an exception (e.g. division by zero), have undesirable side effects (e.g., deleting a needed file) or initiate a lengthy calculation.